# Using a technick how can I get the following that they do not have any specific structure?

Tags: php, dom

From the following HTML code that does not have a specific structure but are just plain , how can I get the: (below you can find what I did using regex)

> 1. 231435424
> 2. 1800cc
> 3. 163bhp
> 4. Automatic
> 5. Petrol
> 6. Blue

Here is the HTML code

```
<td class="details">
    <a href="./view/3505089/"><span class="p_t">Audi A4</span></a>
    <a class="info" href="./view/3505089/">(Details)</a><br>
    <div class="attribs">
        Roadster
        <br>
        P.O: 35562, <span class="p_l">BURON</span>, Phone. 231435424<br>
        1800cc,
        163bhp,
        Automatic,
        Petrol,
        Blue,
    </div>
</td>
```

Here is what I was doing with regex

```
$bhps = array();
$gears = array();

preg_match_all('/(\d{2,3})bhp\b,/', $str2b, $bhps);
preg_match_all('#(A(.*?)tomatic|Ma(.*?)ual)#u', $str2b, $gears);

foreach .......
    $bhp = $bhps[1][$key];
    $gear = $gears[1][$key];
    ........
```

Comment: Are you trying to scrape a website's output? If not then if you can add some tags around your output then that would help to target spcific stuff

Comment: If you the values are coming out in the same order each time you can do a split on comma and referrer to the position in the array that correlates to the value you are looking for

Comment: @pal4life unfortunately I can not add any tags because I scrape.

Comment: @SethMcClaine I guess this is one possible solution. The values are coming out in the same order everytime.

Comment: The classic [don't parse XML/HTML with RegExp](http://stackoverflow.com/q/701166/570812). Use DOM to find `div.attribs span.p_l` and extract info.